# (Javscript/HTML) How to make JavaScript display mulitplication table by jumping columns in nested loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I intended for this to display as a multiplication table but unfortunately when the loop reaches 1x10 it keeps displaying 2x1 and so on as part of the same column instead of moving to a new one.

My first loop is just meant to be the labels for each column above the horizontal rule. This part is fine, the nested loop afterwards is where I'm having the issue.

How can I make the loop jump columns when the j loop is complete? Thanks

```
<body>
    <pre>
    <script>


        for(i=1;i<11;i++)
        {
            document.write('\t\t'+i);
        }

        document.write("<hr>");


        for(i=1;i<11;i++)
            {
            for(j=1;j<11;j++)
                {
                document.write('\t\t'+i+'X'+j+'='+i*j);
                document.write("<br>");
                document.writeln("\n");
                }               
            }


    </script>
    </pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you print this out row by row instead of column by column like this:

```
<body>
    <pre>
    <script>


        for(i=1;i<11;i++)
        {
            document.write('\t\t'+i);
        }

        document.write("<hr>");


        for(i=1;i<11;i++)
            {
            for(j=1;j<11;j++)
                {
                document.write('\t\t'+j+'X'+i+'='+i*j);
                }   
            document.write("<br>");
            document.writeln("\n");
            }


    </script>
    </pre>
</body>
```

I can't think of an easy way to be able to do it column by column only using document.write and document.writeln.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!